# Trying to run Javascript on AJAX call

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, javascript

I am trying to change the classes for the "View cart" button after adding an item to the cart. What I tried to do is to hook into the "woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart" action and insert my Javascript as below but this Breaks the AJAX call. I honestly don't know if I am using the correct hook:

```
function set_button_classes() {

    echo "<script>document.getElementByClassName('added_to_cart wc-forward').classList.add('ct-cart-item', 'ct-offcanvas-trigger');</script>";

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', 'set_button_classes', 10, 1 );
```

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: ˋadd_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', 'set_button_classes', 10, 0 );` will be fairer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281966/run-javascript-code-after-ajax-add-to-cart-event-in-woocommerce). It does work but I am having timing issues I think. They are unrelated to the question though so I will mark the below as the answer. Thanks all.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart' );
function trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
                    // Testing output on browser JS console
                    console.log('added_to_cart'); 
                    // Your code goes here
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by your method I would suggest hooking into `wp_footer` as well, so that your script would be near the end of the body, that way it will be loaded after all DOM was loaded.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', 'set_button_classes');
function set_button_classes () {
    add_action('wp_footer', function () {
        echo "<script>document.getElementByClassName('added_to_cart wc-forward').classList.add('ct-cart-item', 'ct-offcanvas-trigger');</script>";
    });
}
```

You could also close the php tag and reopen it in the `wp_footer` anonymos function to make it easier to understand/see the scrip code

```php
add_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', 'set_button_classes');
function set_button_classes () {
    add_action('wp_footer', function () {
        ?>
        <script>
            document.getElementByClassName('added_to_cart wc-forward').classList.add('ct-cart-item', 'ct-offcanvas-trigger');
        </script>
        <?php
    });
}
```